# How to use array in function to get only value I want

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to work this function in wordpress theme the way where I can get value only what I want and not all to gather. I am not much familiar with using array in function so I need you expert help to make it works and I would really appreciate that.

Here is my code

```
function gallery_artist($arg=null, $arg2=null, $arg3=null){

    global $png_gallery_meta;
    $png_gallery_meta->the_meta();

    $gallery = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $png_gallery_meta->get_the_id(), TRUE);

    $gallery_value = $gallery['image_artist'];
    $artist_info = $gallery_value;

    $string = $artist_info;
    $artist = substr($string, 0, stripos($string, "/") );

    // getting first name and last name from user id
    $author_first_name = get_userdata(basename($string))->first_name;

    $author_last_name = get_userdata(basename($string))->last_name;

    $author_full_name = $author_first_name . ' ' . $author_last_name;

    $user_id = '<a href=" ' . get_author_posts_url(basename($string)) . ' " title="more submissions of ' . $author_first_name .' '. $author_last_name . ' " >' . $artist . '</a>';


    $arg = $author_first_name;      
    echo $arg;

    $arg2 = $author_last_name;      
    echo $arg2;

    $arg3 = $user_id;
    echo $arg3;     

}
```

After than I want to use this function to get any value I want and not unnecessary to render all three to gather. Means if I want only first name than I pass value only for that and it will render only first name so on..

Here how I want to use something. but you can suggest any code and type of function I have no issue.

```
<?php call_user_func_array('gallery_artist', array('first_name','last_name','artist_id') ) ?>
```

Big Big thanks to you all..

Comment: this might do better on the WordPress Stack Exchange, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Alright! I will do but in terms of php you expert also can guide me or it is really wordpress specific issue which may I didn't realized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the bottom section with this:

```
if(!is_null($arg))
{
    $arg = $author_first_name;      
    echo $arg;
}

if(!is_null($arg2))
{
    $arg2 = $author_last_name;      
    echo $arg2;
}

if(!is_null($arg3))
{
    $arg3 = $user_id;
    echo $arg3;
}
```